# I am making a typerace bot (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code:-

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', help_command = None)

tr_questions_file = open("typerace_questions.txt", 'r')
tr_total_q = 10 # total number or questions
tr_questions = []

@client.command(aliases = ['tr', 'typeRace'])
async def typerace(ctx):
    starttime = time.time()
    num = random.randint(0, tr_total_q)
    question = tr_questions[num-1]
    print(question)
    timer = 30.0
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "TYPE RACE", description = f"{question}")
    await ctx.reply(embed = embed)

    def is_correct(msg):
        return msg.author==ctx.author

    try:
        guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=is_correct, timeout=timer)
        print(guess.content)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await ctx.reply("You took too long to type :(")

    if guess.content == question:
        fintime = time.time()
        total = fintime - starttime
        await ctx.send(f"You got it!!\nYou got it in {round(total)} seconds")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Nope, that is not correct!!\nTry again using ``>tr``")

client.run(token)
```

In discord:-
[look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps1C0.png)

In terminal:-
[look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF4L7.png)

both the question and answer are matching, but it is still saying wrong. i have no idea what is happining.

Comment: why don't you simply send question variable instead of f"{question}" ?

Comment: I tried that too. but does not work

Comment: maybe there's an error with the interpreter, because of the try-except syntax. If you look well, your else may be read like the else of the try-except block

Comment: Send screenshot of the output of the the two prints

Comment: @WasiMaster, look at the second link

Comment: Does it fix anything if you call `.strip()` on both of them? There might be trailing whitespace somewhere, which you won't see in your console. So try `if guess.content.strip() == question.strip()`.

Comment: btw instead of getting a random index then getting the item from the index, you can just do random.choice(list) and it will return a random item from the list

Comment: @WasiMaster putting everything in a list is very tough as i now have 200+ sentences. So i dont think so it is usefull

Comment: @stijndcl wow `.strip()` worked thank you